# What is the need to finish a segment tree with zeroes where elements are empty?

Tags: arrays, data-structures, segment-tree

I work with segment trees now. It is known that segment trees has 2^n leaves. Let us imagine an array `data` that consists of 5 elements [1, 2, 3, 4, 5] and is basic for a segment tree. We also have an array `tree_data` containing the tree itself (the right half of `tree_data` contains elements of `data`). It would be logical to allocate 5 elements in `tree_data` to contain elements from `data`, but it is stated that we have to fill the other three elements with zeroes to make the right half of `tree_data` consist of 8 elements and contain [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 0, 0, 0].
[image: segment tree from an example]
Why should we do this instead of saving memory by filling the array with only five elements? Why do we need nodes 7, 14, 15 (see image) to create a segment tree?